# Is that good idea to disable gpg signin for code commits

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code, gnupg

I am using `VS Code` IDE with `Angular` in Windows 11. I have installed latest version of `Git`. When I do my code commit from Visual Studio Code. I am getting many errors Like

```
gpg: skipped "DFDFD": No secret key
```

Other one

```
Error: cannot spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe: No such file or directory
```

If one is getting fixed other one started coming. How can I disable GPG for my code commit ? Is that good idea to disable it first of all ?

**Edit 1**
After running `git config --global commit.gpgsign false` command in Bash, getting below error. I opened Bash as admin

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file - -S
gpg: skipped "DFDFD": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Comment: Signing commits only really makes sense if someone needs to prove it was *you* who made the commit. That's rarely a necessity.

Comment: No, I don't use VS Code. That seems more appropriate to ask at [so] or [su].

Comment: Note that the `-S` in the generated command tells Git to sign the commit, regardless of the default configured setting. In other words, your IDE is overriding your config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Repository Level

To do it at the user level, run the following in whatever command-line tool you have.

```bash
git config commit.gpgsign false
```

##### Global Level

Run this command to disable the setting globally using thee `--global` flag.

```bash
git config --global commit.gpgsign false
```

On Windows, you might need to run this as an administrator.
Likewise—for a native *nix system (macOS, Linux, BSD) you should prefix with `sudo` to perform the action as a super user. If you are using `wsl` on Windows, then you may first need to run the following in order to act as root:

```
wsl --user root
```

##### VS Code Workspace

Type `Cmd`+`Shift`+`P` on macOS, or `Ctrl`+`,` on Windows, and open your settings. There are workspace settings and user settings. Uncheck "Enable Commit Signing" if it's enabled.

[image: screenshot of settings in VS code]

If that doesn't work, it's got to be something with the local Git repository, or perhaps has to do with some other extension as it's overriding your global settings with `useConfigOnly=true`.

Finally, you can try the above Repository Level settings from a terminal that's opened at the path of the Git repository in question. You can do this in VS code by typing `Ctrl`+`Opt`+`` ` `` or going to *Terminal > New Terminal* and executing the command there.

[image: screenshot of terminal in VS Code]